# mechanism to withdraw flags: suggestion

Tags: feature-request, flags

I realise there is currently no mechanism to withdraw flags. (I.e., this isn't a duplicate post, as far as I can tell.)

I think it would be nice to have a mechanism whereby one can withdraw a flag, rather than simply wait for someone to dispute or decline the flag. After all, with a very thorough edit, the reasons for a flag might vanish -- and the fact that the post was successfully edited might persuade me that the post perhaps was flagged in error.  Such a mechanism would spare someone from then having to review the flag.

Is this possible/feasible?

Comment: +1 - I would like this too - I recently flagged a post as "not an answer" and the poster edited it a few minutes later which made my flag look stupid and therefore got declined.

Comment: @Bart, this isn't a duplicate because I'm not asking if cancelling a flag can be done. I know it cannot be, as I read several (duplicate) posts here in meta asking that question before I posted mine. I am asking, rather, if that feature that currently doesn't exist can be introduced.

Comment: @DerekHenderson That post is also a feature request. I think it's a dup.

Comment: As @Doorknob says, that question was also a feature request. It's therefore not merely asking if such a feature exists but also, if it doesn't, if such a feature could be implemented. Making this a duplicate. That said, I'm pretty sure that is not the only duplicate. This idea has come up various times before.